# The title of viewpager is hidden

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have Viewpager in my activity and three fragments in it. But the title of those fragments are hidden.

I googled about it but did not find the right solution.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar_layout">

        </include>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="464dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="103dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my tabspageradapter class where I give titles for those fragments:

```
package com.example.user.messingaround;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position)
            {
            case 0:
                RequestsFragment requestsFragment = new RequestsFragment();
                return requestsFragment;

            case 1:
                ChatsFragment chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
                return chatsFragment;

            case 2:
                FriendsFragment friendsFragment = new FriendsFragment();
                return friendsFragment;

            default:
                return null;
            }
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount()

    {
        return 3;
    }


    public CharSequence getTitle(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return "Requests";

            case 1:
                return "Chats";

            case 2:
                return "Friends";

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my activity class where I initialize my viewpager:

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.main_view_pager);
    tabsPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabsPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    mtoolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MyChat");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden", exactly? Can you see the tabs at all? Can you see your toolbar? That layout looks like it will have the `ViewPager` overlapping the `AppBarLayout` completely. What happens if you add `android:id="@+id/app_bar"` to the `<AppBarLayout>`, and `android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"` to the `<ViewPager>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your xml is not correct try my code which has few more line of code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/TabStyle"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

If still face issue try this link: https://android.jlelse.eu/tablayout-and-viewpager-in-your-android-app-738b8840c38a